# Why does my dictionary lookup give a SQL timeout error?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Part of my application uses road names which are stored in a SQL database. The application will access every name record at least once and most will be accessed multiple times. So I decided to load the names data into a dictionary and then look-up against that to reduce the database reads.

The road names table has ~3 million records and I use the following Linq-to-SQL to load it into memory;

```
Dictionary<String, DbRoadName> roadNames;

using (RoutingDataContext dc = new RoutingDataContext(connectionString))
{
    roadNames = dc.DbRoadNames.ToDictionary(x => x.RoadId);
}
```

This executes as expected. Stopping the code at this point and putting the mouse over the roadNames variable in Visual Studio shows that the dictionary appears to contain the expected key-value pairs.

However, when I get to the following line later in the program

```
DbRoadName roadName = roadNames[lookupId];
```

the program stops with the following exception

> .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Timeout expired.

As I understand it, the `ToDictionary()` method should cause the database query to execute at that point, so why am I getting a SQL timeout error at the dictionary lookup?

**Update:**
I 'fixed' the problem by replacing

```
DbRoadName roadName = roadNames[lookupId];
```

with a TryGetValue statement. However, I'm still interested in why the in-memory dictionary was producing a SQL exception.

Comment: Full exception details (or something more than the Message at least) could help

Comment: Wow put a roadNames.Count right after that using.  My guess is deferred execution.

Comment: @Blam I did that. The count shows the correct value but the exception still occurs on the lookup.

Comment: Check your DbRoadName properties and constructor. If there's a value missing somewhere maybe you coded a get to obtain the data individually if it wasnt returned by the database, at which point this could all be a specific data error

Comment: What is DbRoadName?   I would expect to see a Dictionary Int, String

Comment: @Blam, DbRoadName is the designer-generated Linq-to-SQL object that corresponds to a record in the DbRoadNames table. So the dictionary is holding that object as the value in each key-value pair.

Comment: It's almost certainly deferred execution for something in `DbRoadNames`. Yes, calling `ToDictionary` will force execution to get them, but won't force getting all the navigation properties. As Blam asked, *What is DbRoadName*? It's understood that it's an object, and a record from the table, but does it contain references to other objects?

Comment: If all you need is a lookup to road name then why not use  Dictionary Int, String.  Is x.RoadId really a string?

Comment: DdRoadName is a simple object containing 4 strings (which contain the Id, the name, the road class and the road number). The table isn't related to any others in the database and the only index is the primary key (on the record id). That is, it's about as simple as a table can be.

Comment: Since you dispose of your datacontext (using..) I doubt it is defered loading. I would expect a null reference exception in that case and not a timeout since your datacontext is gone there can be no loading anymore.

Comment: DbRoadName roadName = roadNames[lookupId]; is inside the using()?

Comment: @Flaudre - no, the dictionary lookup is in an entirely separate subroutine (to which the roadNames dictionary is passed as a parameter).

Comment: Did you take a look at the generated SQL queries? Those could help in understanding what is happening.

Comment: what is a 'RoutingDataContext'? Can't find anything about that. Also could you put a breakpoint behind the using statement and try to access the properties of an element inside that dictionary? Try to access the properties of the first element and one element further down the list.

Comment: `Dictionary` does not support deferred execution in any way. That dict *was* materialized as expected. This exception cannot be caused by that line (except if roadNames or lookupId were properties executing queries...). You are looking at the wrong line. Sometimes VS marks the wrong line (off by one). Or, old PDB symbols. Deferred execution did not happen in any way in this line.

Comment: @usr, I agree that deferred execution seems unlikely, given both that it's a dictionary and that the data context used to fill it is closed. However, over the course of several builds (as I tried to identify/fix the error), it always stopped at the given look-up statement as I stepped through the code.

Comment: @SteveBird are you still interested in this question?

Comment: @usr, I suppose that now I've got a work-around it's not important to me to find an answer. However, I'm still curious as to the original cause as there may be a mechanism I'm misunderstanding. If I get some spare time, I might create a small program to retry the original code in a more isolated environment and see what happens.

Comment: My advice would be to set the debugger to break on all exceptions and see what's on top of the stack. That will show where exactly the exception happened.

Answer (score 1):

to avoid the SQL timeout i would not load the Storage-Model in my dictionary. Instead load the data As Model with the necessary properties like this:

```
Dictionary<String, DbRoadNameModel> roadNameModelDictionary;
using (RoutingDataContext dc = new RoutingDataContext(connectionString))
{
    roadNames = dc.DbRoadNames
        .Select(roadName => new DbRoadNameModel(roadName.RoadId, roadName.Prop1, roadName.Prop2))
        .ToDictionary(x => x.RoadId);
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: I did something very similar, with a very simple new poco object holding the data in the dictionary. To my surprise, I still got the SQL timeout at the dictionary access even though the dictionary didn't contain any database objects.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion from Steffenn Winkler or Flaudre? Access a element from the dictionary inside the using-Statement. Maybe usr is right, and the Exception is missleading.